# Can I upgrade just one account to Google Workspace for Business?

Tags: google-workspace-for-business

Can I upgrade just one account to Google Workspace for Business?

Is there a way to upgrade my account only? I need more than 10GB of storage space.
All other users on my domain have aprox 10% used space. We are 36 users in total  so will be a waste of money ( 1800 USD/ year for 25GB storage space)

I understand that I need get all other users to a Suborganization.
Please send me your solutions.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to upgrade just one account to Google Apps for Business. However, a workaround is to purchase storage only for *yourself*.

From the [support article](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047457?hl=en):

> **The extra storage is only available to you.** You can't share it with other users or transfer it to another account. You can't purchase storage for other users.

You can purchase storage for Gmail and Google Drive combined [here](https://www.google.com/settings/storage).

Comment: The link only takes me to a page that shows all my storage but does not allow me to purchase extra storage for my user

Answer (score 0):

Google has the option to upgrade only one user however one of the requirements is to have at least 100 users, therefore in your case the best option is to purchase additional storage only for your account.

Comment: Please add the source of the referred option.

Answer (score 0):

Log in as a user you'd like to buy storage for and go to https://drive.google.com/settings/storage.

You may need to enable options to allow users to expand their storage:

Turn on the option to buy more storage

As a super administrator, turn on each of these additional services:

- Individual storage
- Google Play
- Google Payments

https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047457

Answer (score -5):

Just create new user (e.x. drive-depot@your-company.com) and transfer your files to that new user.

Here is how:

[image]

I've google free apps account and that worked great for me :)